# google apps script scheduled tasks

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I just tried the scheduled trigger by time (1 min) for my Google Sheet in Apps Script and to my surprise the function does not perform the same procedure as if I execute it manually... what could be the reason? any clue there? The function randomly selects cells, colors them, and timestamps them on another sheet. It does this perfectly with manual execution of the function, but with scheduled execution, it does not color the cells and takes data from where it should not.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem. - [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: A possibility is that you are using the getActiveSheet() method and when run from a trigger it always returns SpreadSheet.getSheets()[0] which may be different from when it is run by a user that has create a ui. When a script is run by a trigger no ui is create because there is no user.

Comment: Yes, Cooper, that was the problem. From now on I program all my scripts pointing to the specific sheet on which I am going to work. Thank you so much.